# How to choose canonical when one desktop URL is broken up into several mobile URLs?

Tags: canonical-url, mobile, desktop

I have an adaptive website, and in the mobile version, we put the same data as the desktop version, but in special tabs which are accessible via route URL change.

For example, we have the `profile` page, in desktop, it's only the `/profile` page. But in the `mobile` page, there are several tabs. For example: `/profile?tab=about`, `/profile?tab=posts`, and more.

The canonical for the mobile page is exactly as same as the currently active tab (ex: `/profile?tab=posts`) and for the desktop version is `/profile`

Google use SmartPhone bot to crawl the website, so it gets multiple canonical, and in the website, it handled that without redirecting or anything else, it shows the page. For example when desktop user come to `/profile?tab=posts`, he or she will see the desktop content of `/profile` which is for desktop.

Is this a good way to handle mobile and desktop canonical?  or for all pages, I need to use only `/profile`

Comment: What is the reason that the mobile site has the tabs?  Is it because of screen real-estate, or download speed, or something else?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's our design system, and for providing better mobile version and for UX purposes we use tab.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller So how would you handle that? What I'm doing here is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the content is the same on desktop and mobile, and the only difference is the way that you display the content to users on mobile devices, then I believe that you're making this more difficult than it needs to be.

If your tabs are constructed with a `<ul>`, just use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to control the breakpoints when your tab styles should get applied. Then you clean up your URLs and you set your canonical normally.

In this case your canonicals are really important because you're using query parameters. There are no redirects either. While Google can read them, query parameters are generally avoided by SEOs so that search engines don't have to try to guess about how to deal with the duplicate content.

Responsive design is what Google recommends, primarily for this reason. Separate URL configurations are difficult to implement and even more of a chore to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two site variants, for desktop and for mobile devices, you should have any logic to route users to certain site version. Lets assume, it is media query, which decides, which site version is to deliver.
That is the method to deliver canonical:

- if deliver desktop version - include the desktop canonical,
- if deliver mobile version - include mobile canonical.

Google describes pretty detailedly how to deal with canonicals in this setup: https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls

Comment: Where does Google address a setup with a many-to-one URL mapping between mobile and desktop?

Comment: i would say, it implies using own canonical for each page. I wouldn't call it many-to-one - they are just different. Or have i a logic bug?

Comment: They say they break a desktop page up into several tabs on mobile and each tab gets its own URL.

Comment: So i would create canonical according to current url. Something like `<link rel="canonical" href="
<?php
$url =  "//$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']";
$escaped_url = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo $escaped_url;
?>
" />`